# How to get information about current buffer/file in emacs?

Tags: emacs

When working on a buffer (that maps to a certain file) , how to get info about it?
Like Path on disk, size, ...

Comment: Just for my own curiousity, did you want something that would give a one line, say in the minibuffer or did you mean going into dired mode and seeing all the directories and files and info like has been suggested below? It may be 'neat' to see current buffer/file info in the minbuffer as a quick reminder.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`M-x dired RET`

Comment: C-x D (RET) as standard keybinding apparently, tx

Answer (score 7):

Additionally, there's `dired-x` which has `dired-jump` - this allows you to go straight to the file you're visiting. `dired-x.el` appears to be shipped with my emacs-22.1, so it should suffice to say

```
(require 'dired-x)
```

in your `~/.emacs`. That installs the binding `C-x C-j` for `dired-jump`.

Answer (score 6):

`C-x C-b` opens *Buffer List*, which includes path and size info.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want the path and don't want to open dired mode, following will display the full path in the mini buffer and copy it to clipboard. I find it very useful. Put this in your .emacs

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f8>") 'copy-buffer-file-name)
```

Comment: that is not working on my emacs/ubuntu 23.1.1.  it says "symbol's function definition is void: copy-buffer-file-name"

Comment: There's a [buffer-extension](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/buffer-extension.el) - and it has `copy-buffer-file-name-as-kill` function. It even asks You what to copy: name, full name or a directory name.

Answer (score 1):

Command `describe-file` (bound to <kbd>C-h M-f</kbd>), here:

[help-fns+.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/help-fns%2b.el) -- [***Help+***](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HelpPlus.)

In [***Dired+***](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus), just hit <kbd>C-h RET</kbd> to invoke `describe-file` on the current line.